# Frozen Formalism Problem

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, adm-formalism

Before stating my question, let me say what I do understand:
In the ADM formalism, the Hamiltonian density of the gravitational field can be written as,

$$\mathcal{H} = h n + H_a N^a$$

where n is the lapse function and $N^a$ is the shift vector field ($h$ and $H^a$ are densities).
If we vary the lapse $n$ and the shift $N$, we obtain
$h = 0$ (scalar constraint equation / Hamiltonian constraint)
$H_a = 0$ (vector constraint equation / momentum constraint)
However, we can still vary the spatial metric and the canonical momenta to obtain the ADM evolution equations which are compatible with these constraint equations.

I understand that – by virtue of the constraints – the Hamiltonian vanishes on-shell (if we neglect boundary terms for the moment), but I fail to understand in which sense "nothing evolves". Does this have to do with the choice of the configuration space?

In appendix E.2 of "General Relativity", Wald mentions a certain quotient space called "superspace" which effectively eliminates the momentum constraint. However, I think that the evolution equation should not become trivial on this restricted configuration space.

For people who are not so familiar with the ADM formalism, I can recommend the following literature:

[[1](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/piotr.chrusciel/teaching/Cauchy/Roscoff.pdf)] Wald, General Relativity – in particular appendix E.2 on the Hamiltonian formulation of GR.

[2] [Chruściel, Cauchy problems for the Einstein Equations](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/piotr.chrusciel/teaching/Cauchy/Roscoff.pdf) - section 1.4 is a quite readable introduction to the geometry of non-degenerate submanifolds (induced metric, second fundamental form) with elementary proofs of the Gauß- and the Codazzi-Mainardi equation, which yield the constraint equations when applied to the Einstein equation.

Comment: Why do you say "nothing evolves"? Is this something you've read/heard? In that case a source would be useful. (At the moment is hard to understand exactly what you are asking.)

Comment: I think the OP might be mixing the "problem of time" in the Wheeler-DeWitt equation and the fact that the classical evolution is generated by Hamiltonian constraints. (Not unrelated issues, but not the same as well.)

Comment: @mmeent By "_nothing evolves_" I mean that the Hamiltonian is a pure constraint, so nothing evolves.